# Ponteiros em Go

Tags: ponteiro, golang

Estou tentando alterar uma String em Go usando ponteiros, porem eu recebo um

```
invalid operation: oculta[i] (type *string does not support indexing)
```

A função que estou realizando a alteração.

```
func verifica(palavra, chute string, oculta *string) {
    for i, l := range palavra {
        if string(l) == chute {
            *oculta[i] = chute
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sobre string: strings em go são imutaveis, ou seja tirando metodos especicos para o tipo string ela n pode ser modificada, a não ser que esteja atribuido algo nela por completo

ponteiros: para evitar ambiguidades a maneira de acessar um ponteiro com o uso de indices é `(*ptr)[i]`

pelo q entendi do codigo, vc quer atribuir a letra do chute na oculta, como não pode manipular o indice da string diretamente para atribuir(para acessar em um print por exemplo, pode), isso aq seria uma solução para o que creio que seja o objetivo dessa função

```
func verifica(palavra, chute string, nome *string) {
    for _, l := range palavra {
        if string(l) == chute {
            *nome = *nome + chute
        } else {
            *nome = *nome + "_"
        }
    }
}
```

para utilizar indices a solução acho que seria usar [slice](https://go-tour-br.appspot.com/moretypes/7) de byte(byte é meio que o char do golang)

```
func verifica(palavra, chute string, nome []byte) {
    for i, l := range palavra {
        if string(l) == chute {
            nome[i] = byte(chute[0])
        } else {
            nome[i] = byte("_"[0])
        }
    }
}
```

slice é um ponteiro, então n precisa receber com `*`e nem mandar com `&`, a unica coisa é que antes de mandar ele tem que criar ele do tamanho que vai usar, antes de essa função ser chamada

```
nome := make([]byte, len(palavra))
```

da para usar slice com [append](https://go-tour-br.appspot.com/moretypes/15) tb

Comment: Só para complementar, `byte` é impróprio para armazenar caracteres, pois ele tem apenas 8 bits de precisão, o que não é o bastante para armazenar caracteres unicode que requerem 32 bits, como emojis ou kanji por exemplo. Prefira o tipo `rune` para esses casos.